# Azure functions takes too long to scale out

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure HttpTrigger function which processes POST requests and scales out on heavy load. The issue is that the caller of the function only waits 3 sec. for a HTTP 200 status code.
But when an azure function scales out it takes 4-6 sec. until the request gets processed. If the caller sends a request during the scale out it is possible that he cancels the request and my service is never be able to process it. Which is a worst case scenario.

Is there a way to prevent that? My ideal scenario would be an immediate HTTP 202 answer to the caller. But I'm afraid that this is not possible during a scale out process.

Comment: If you're using consumption-based plan, you'll likely see a bit of delay when scaling out. Higher-level tiers provide pre-warmed instances.

Comment: Hey @t2t did you ever solve this? I've run into exactly the same problem. Even the parameters of my problem are (were?) the same as yours. Did you end up moving to a premium functions plan, or were you able to solve it another way? Cheers :)

Comment: @wislon I ended up rebuilding it into a queue system. The POST endpoint put all requests into a azure service bus and response immediatly with a 200. Additionally I added a time trigger function which calls my main endpoint every 5 minutes (to keep it warm). This is cheaper than the premium plan. But I guess I will switch to the premium plan at some point.

Comment: @tzt are you me? coz that's exactly what I did. I suspect we're dealing with the same caller. If it helps, I also tried the premium plan for a bit, and that did resolve the issue. I switched back to the consumption plan, for now, until it starts manifesting again.

Comment: @wislon my caller is tradingview.com good to know that the premium plan fix that!

Comment: @t2t yep, thought so :)

Answer (score 2):

**A Scale-out will require your app to be loaded onto another instance so some delay occurs/incur for those requests because of time taken to load your app onto the new instance**.

As described in the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#cold-start-behavior):

**Consumption Plan** is the true serverless hosting plan since it enables scaling to zero when idle state, but some requests might have additional latency at startup.

To get constant **low latency** with autoscaling, you should move to the **[premium hosting plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#premium-plan)** which **avoids cold starts** with perpetually warm instances.